# Is there any implementation of atomic methods in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, critical-section

**Hello guys**

I'd like to ask, if is there any type of implementation ,that can be used to set method/part of code as atomic operation in `Java`, so it can't be stopped/paused (must be executed to the end). I need that for ensure that while I am buffering `MP3` file to buffer, represented as front of frames that has size of bit rate of that file, the thread will read the whole frame, or the operation will fail to be done, but to avoid that buffer will read only a part of frame, to avoid tears in playing, and errors in data consistence.

I am asking because there will be multiple threads working with that file (*BufferClass*, *PlayerClass*, *FileInfoClass*, etc..) and the file will be implemented as typical example of `Critical Part` of data, so there will be synchronization through a monitor. Maybe that can be served by some avoid of call `Thread.wait()` / `Thread.notify()` but I am not that advanced in `Java`.

Comment: Atomicity is relative. You achieve it through monitor locking with synchronized blocks.

Comment: I can't tell from your question whether you are asking how to create a mutex (i.e., prevent multiple threads from modifying the same data at the same time), or whether you are asking for some kind of performance guarantee (i.e., insure that this thread will not be preempted until it finishes the job.)  The first two answers below tell you how to do mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the synchronized statement:

```
synchronized(anObject){
    performSomeOperation();
}
```

Every synchronized statement using the same object is guaranted to wait until another thread in such a statement is finished.

Example for Hot Licks comment:

```
synchronized returntype someMethod(parameters ...){
    performSomeOperation();
}
```

In this example the object which is locked is 'this'.

Comment: And you can make the entire method synchronized, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the accepted answer, you may find it useful to also take a look at the *already available* (since Java SE 5) [Java Concurrency Utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/index.html).

**API Specification:**

- [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) Package
- [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) Package
- [java.util.concurrent.locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) Package

From the official description (emphasis mine):

> The concurrency utilities packages provide a **powerful, extensible
>   framework of high-performance threading utilities** such as thread pools
>   and blocking queues. This package frees the programmer from the need
>   to craft these utilities by hand, in much the same manner the
>   collections framework did for data structures. Additionally, these
>   packages provide low-level primitives for **advanced concurrent
>   programming**.

For instance, *java.util.concurrent.locks* package provides an **alternative** to the classical *synchronized* blocks:

> While locking is built into the Java language through the
>   *synchronized* keyword, there are a number of limitations to built-in
>   monitor locks. The *java.util.concurrent.locks* package provides a
>   high-performance lock implementation with the same memory semantics as
>   synchronization, and it also supports specifying a timeout when
>   attempting to acquire a lock, multiple condition variables per lock,
>   nonnested ("hand-over-hand") holding of multiple locks, and support
>   for interrupting threads that are waiting to acquire a lock.

See the [Concurrency Utilities Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/overview.html) for more.

---

**Useful reading**

- [The Java Tutorials:
  Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)
- [Java concurrency: Building and testing concurrent applications for
  the Java
  platform](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/training/kp/j-kp-concurrency/)
- [Java 101: Java concurrency without the
  pain](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078809/java-concurrency/java-101--the-next-generation--java-concurrency-without-the-pain--part-1.html)

Comment: Can it be used on Object, or only for primitive types ?

Comment: @JánSrniček The classes in those packages are **already** made to used in the concurrent applications, i.e. this is already done *for you*. A simple classical example is [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) that can be used in applications such as atomically incremented counters (see [Atomic Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html)). Using them or not is up to you, it's just now creating a concurrent application is a little easier...